# filter dataframe based on 2 conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have the following example DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A'], 'col2': [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]})
```

Now, I would like to create a second DataFrame containing only the rows from `df` where:

col1 - A matches col2: 0 and
col1 - B matches col2: 1

```
df2 = pandasDataFrame({'col1' : ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A'], 'col2' : [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]})
```

I have tried with query, but it is only working on one condition, if I separate condition pair in parenthesis, I get an empty DataFrame.

Comment: What is `A`? A string?

Comment: Use `df[(df.col1.eq('A') & df.col2.eq(0)) | (df.col1.eq('B') & df.col2.eq(1))]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use create a boolean mask and filter:

```
out = df[(df['col1'].eq('A')&df['col2'].eq(0)) | (df['col1'].eq('B') & df['col2'].eq(1))]
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2
0    A     0
1    A     0
2    B     1
5    B     1
6    A     0
9    A     0
```

Comment: Can you convert to wiki?